# SQL dynamic query for insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamicquery

I have a SQL Server table with these columns:

```
Product | QTY | DISCREPANCIES
```

and I want to insert multiple records using a stored procedure.

Inputs for my procedure are :

```
    declare @Product varchar(50) = 'product1';
    declare @QTY int = 1;
    declare @DISCREPANCIES1 varchar(50) = 'Defected';
    declare @DISCREPANCIES2 varchar(50) = 'Shorted';
    declare @DISCREPANCIES3 varchar(50) = 'DifferentProduct';
    declare @DISCREPANCIES4 varchar(50) = 'Extra';
    declare @DISCREPANCIESQTY1 int = 1;
    declare @DISCREPANCIESQTY2 int = 1;
    declare @DISCREPANCIESQTY3 int = 1;
    declare @DISCREPANCIESQTY3 int = 1;
```

I want the inserted output like :

```
product1 |  1  | Defected
product1 |  1  | Shorted
product1 |  1  | DifferentProduct
product1 |  1  | Extra
```

How can I insert these values using while loop or using anything else?

Answer (score 0):

This is literally a basic insert, though I don't understand why you are taking in 4 rows of data versus passing in a table type parameter.

```
insert into someTable (Product, QTY, DISCREPANCIES)
values
(@Product,@DISCREPANCIESQTY1,@DISCREPANCIES1),
(@Product,@DISCREPANCIESQTY2,@DISCREPANCIES2),
(@Product,@DISCREPANCIESQTY3,@DISCREPANCIES3)
```

Also, you didn't explain what these parameters are for or how they are related so I don't know if you want to use `@QTY` or the ones above. Anyways, you get the picture...